# Include text without formatting

Tags: code, text

Suppose this is what I intend to write:

x_state = y_state + 2^3,

However, to keep it as it in the latex, I need to include '\' before every operator. But as I have more of such text, it is tiresome to do so, is there any better way, a package maybe? such that if you put your text in the environment it will be displayed as it is?

thanks.

Comment: try [verbatim](https://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim)

Comment: Use `\verb!x_state = y_state + 2^3!`, if I've well understood what you want.

Comment: Thank you, DG' and Bernard. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @DG', use of `verbatim` solves the issue. Thanks.